# scroll conflict on dom elements

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

There are two div on my demo, I want to scroll the different div but not both.

I have been written the console.log('left');　and console.log('left');　.
It seems conflict when I just need left scroll or right scroll .

I got answer by hsz , but my question seems hard to clarify :(

```
// console:left
        document.getElementById('body').onscroll = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('num').scrollTop = document.get`enter code here`ElementById('body').scrollTop;
            console.log('left');

        }


// console:right
        document.getElementById('num').onscroll = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('body').scrollTop = document.getElementById('num').scrollTop;
            console.log('right');

        }
```

https://codepen.io/AsheLi/pen/djexyE?editors=1111

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!
Your question is pretty hard to understand, I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then editing your question. If a question is hard to understand, it is unlikely someone will take the time to try and give you an answer.

Comment: I try to edit my question , is it clarify then last time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to introduce a flag that will specify what has initialized the scrolling - organic scrolling (current scroll done by user) or second div:

```
let organicScrolling = true;

// console:left
document.getElementById('body').onscroll = function(e) {
  if (organicScrolling) {
    document.getElementById('num').scrollTop = document.getElementById('body').scrollTop;
    console.log('left');
  }
  organicScrolling = !organicScrolling;
};

// console:right
document.getElementById('num').onscroll = function(e) {
  if (organicScrolling) {
    document.getElementById('body').scrollTop = document.getElementById('num').scrollTop;
    console.log('right');
  }
  organicScrolling = !organicScrolling;
};
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/hsz/pen/yqEBod?editors=1111)

Comment: wow , it works!   thanks for your answer :D
is this way has knowledge domain or it's a tricks ? 
new to js :(